# mod_rewrite in htaccess with escaped parameter

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, escaping

I want a htaccess redirection from `www.xyz.com/test/123` to `http://www.zxy.de/?learningCardsDeeplinkUrl=http%3A%2F%2Ftest1.test2.com%2Findex.html%23%21%2FflashCard%2F123123`

and try this entry in htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ http://www.zxy.de/?learningCardsDeeplinkUrl=http%3A%2F%2Ftest1.test2.com%2Findex.html%23%21%2FflashCard%2F$1
```

The result is:
`targetUrl=httpAFFtest1.test2.comFindex.html31FflashCardF123`

The % is missing in the target url.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `%` in target URL since `%3`, `%2` etc denote **back-reference** variables from `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ http://www.zxy.de/?learningCardsDeeplinkUrl=http\%3A\%2F\%2Ftest1.test2.com\%2Findex.html\%23\%21\%2FflashCard\%2F$1 [L,R,NE]
```

Comment: The result of this was an redirection with http%253A%252F%252 in the browser url. I need there http%3a%2f%2f without the %25

Comment: Not correct. That means you're not using `NE` flag as I shoed in my answer above. It redirects to `http://www.zxy.de/?learningCardsDeeplinkUrl=http%3A%2F%2Ftest1.test2.com%2Findex.html%23%21%2FflashCard%2F123`

Comment: copy / paste from htaccess: ...\%2Findex.html\%23\%21\%2FflashCard\%2F$1 [L,R,NE]